# Calling notify on a regular Object in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider this snippet of code:

```
Object stateChanged = new Object();
if(state == GLGameState.Finished) {
 //Don't mind those two methods
 screen.pause();
 screen.dispose();
 synchronized(stateChanged) {
 this.state = GLGameState.Idle;
 stateChanged.notifyAll();
     }
 }
```

I'm a bit confused because I have never seen notifyAll/wait called on any object before. How does this work? Before this, I haven't seen anything to make it wait. This is a snippet from the book, Beginning Android Games. I'm not sure if this snippet is enough, but if it is not please let me know. TLDR how does notifyall, notify, and wait work when calling it on an object? All the tutorials I've seen just call wait() or notify() on themselves. Thank you in advance! Edit: Do note that there was no wait() called on stateChanged so far, so that confuses me a bit too.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have indeed read it, though I can't exactly seem to wrap my head around calling wait() or notify() on different objects other than the one being executed

Comment: I don't think so. I compacted it a ton. Yes, stateChanged is in instance scope. For the latter, no, it would not. https://github.com/Apress/beg-android-games-3ed/blob/master/ch07-gl-basics/Ch07/app/src/main/java/com/badlogic/androidgames/framework/impl/GLGame.java has the full code

Answer (score 1):

notify and wait are tools for synchronization between threads - one thread **waits** until it is awoken by a **notification** from another threads.

notify/notifyAll awakens one/all threads that were waiting on that particular object.

If no threads were waiting then notification does nothing.  If there is no code even written in which a thread is waiting on that object, notification is pointless.

Thus, **somewhere** there should be code waiting on stateChanged.

The particular object being waiting/notified is simply an agreement between waiter and notifier ("let's rendezvous at object Foo").  Sometimes it's appropriate for a couple of methods in the same object to use their containing object as the rendezvous point.  Sometimes, as it appears in your example, it's appropriate to add an object just for wait/notify - and in that case it might be the simplest possible object, an actual Object (the base class of all objects).

Comment: Hi and thanks, how would a thread wait on that object? I would do stateChanged.wait, in a different piece of code synchronized under stateChanged? if stateChanged.wait is called, what does that do? It makes all threads reading it wait? Sorry, I've only ever scene wait() and notify() called on the same instance, and this is a bit difficult to wrap my mind around and even explain. Edit: So would a stateChanged.wait cause the thread executing that statement to wait for stateChanged to be notified?

Comment: The thread that executes stateChanged.wait() is the only thread that waits -- the wait call itself does not complete until notification..   Given the name of the variable I'd expect it to be waiting for some "state" to "change".   Elsewhere, I'd expect a different thread to "change" the "state", and then call stateChange to notify the waiter that the "state" had "changed".   The words "state" and "change" here are actions that have specific meaning within the program, of course.  In your example the state just changed to idle - we see the notifier but  not the waiter in the posted snippet.

Comment: Ah okay... so it doesn't matter what class it's in? What if I called wait() in this class instead of the wait() in stateChanged, an instance of Object?

Comment: All that's needed is the wait, notify, and their respective 'synchronized' clauses, to agree on the specific thing they're using to coordinate their activities.  You can view every object as having a queue of threads that are waiting on it, and notify will act on that specific queue.  (This is a conceptual description but it's likely quite close to implementational reality).